# ListBox not available as Control

Tags: windows-phone-8, expression-blend

This is odd.
I just tried to add a ListBox-Control to a XAML-Page in Expression Blend, but a ListBox-Control isn't available?

I have only 15 silverlight-controls in total (Blend) and no ListBox?

This isn't normal right?
What can I do about his?

Comment: Yep I see this too in Blend. I'm guessing it's a subtle hint that you should really be using a `LongListSelector` in WP8 ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use the ListBox control, you can add it in by right-clicking somewhere on the control surface, selecting "View Source", and then typing `<ListBox/>` into the code. Once you've done this, so long as the ListBox remains selected in code, Expression Blend will let you edit it like any normal ListBox